# Can I have a reference to a nested bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I want to have a bean of type *com.a.A* which has several **addressable** properties of type *com.a.B*.

```
<bean id="myCompound" class="com.a.A">
    <property name="first">
        <bean class="com.a.B"/> <!-- Anything else needed here? -->
    </property>
     <property name="second">
        <bean class="com.a.B"/> <!-- Anything else needed here? -->
    </property>
```

In **addressable** I mean, that I would like to be able to have a reference to either one of these nested beans, from another bean:

```
<bean id="myCollaborator" class="com.a.C">
    <property name="target" ref="myCompound.first"/>
</bean>
```

This structure doesn't work, and it seems to me that Spring does not resolve compound properties in <ref> elements. Is that so? Can someone think of a way to work around this?

Comment: Can't you just assign explicit `id`s for `<bean class="com.a.B"/>` and use them in `myCollaborator`? Or even better, define `<bean class="com.a.B"/>` outside...

Comment: @tomasz:  What I needed is for the inner bean to represent an **inner class** of `com.a.A`. The idea of defining a top-level beanreferring to the nested bean, as suggested by @jb,  works: I defined a top-level-bean with `factory-bean="myCompound" factory-method="getFirst"` to get the reference to the inner bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple workaround.

```
<bean id="firstB" class="com.a.B"/>
<bean id="secondB" class="com.a.B"/>

<bean id="myCompound" class="com.a.A">
    <property name="first" ref="firstB"/>
    <property name="second" ref="secondB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myCollaborator" class="com.a.C">
    <property name="target" ref="firstB"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, then Spring 3.0's EL support provides exactly what you're looking for:

```
<bean id='one' class  = 'a.b.C.One' >
  <property name='property1' value ='43433' />
</bean>

<bean class = 'a.b.c.Two'>
 <property name = 'property2' value = "#{ one.property1 }"/>
</bean>
```

and, of course, in Java-style configuration, this is trivial

```
@Configuration 
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean 
    public One one(){ 
     One o = new One();
     o.setProperty1(24324);
     return o;
    }

    @Bean 
    public Two two (){ 
     Two t =new Two();
     t.setProperty2( one().getProperty1());
     return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the expected property is a bean?